# Какое содержимое регистров при использовании прерывания 25h

Tags: cpu

Подскажите какое содержимое регистров при использовании прерывания 25h и вообще как это посмотреть?

Comment: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0027.php

Comment: [ральф браун](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-25.htm), конечно

Comment: Чтобы это посмотреть нужно погуглить.